# Creating nested Json object using JQ

Tags: json, bioinformatics, jq

I need to get the values in Exon of the following Json input and split it by ";" and convert to a nested JSON as show below in the Expected ouput section

### Sample Input

```
  {  
   "regions":[  
      {  
         "metric":"GENE1",
         "value":[  
            {  
               "metric":"Exons",
               "value":[  
                  "GENE1;chr1;45656;5656667"    
               ],
               "type":"set"
            },
            {  
               "metric":"Precent_no_call",
               "value":4.22623,
               "type":"simple"
            },
            {  
               "metric":"Total_NoCall_bases",
               "value":112533,
               "type":"simple"
            }
         ],
         "type":"metrics-set"
      },
      {  
         "metric":"GENE2",
         "value":[  
            {  
               "metric":"Exons",
               "value":[  
                  "GENE2_Exon5;chr1;45656;5656667",
                  "GENE2_Exon10;chr1;45656;5656667"                 
               ],
               "type":"set"
            },
            {  
               "metric":"Precent_no_call",
               "value":0.746464,
               "type":"simple"
            },
            {  
               "metric":"Total_NoCall_bases",
               "value":16842,
               "type":"simple"
            }
         ],
         "type":"metrics-set"
      }
   ]
}
```

### Expected Output

```
{  
   "regions":[  
      {  
         "metric":"GENE1",
         "value":[  
            {  
               "metric":"Exons",
               "value":[  
                  "GENE1",
                  {  
                     "chromosome":"chr1",
                     "start":45656,
                     "end":5656667
                  }
               ],
               "type":"set"
            },
            {  
               "metric":"Precent_no_call",
               "value":4.22623,
               "type":"simple"
            },
            {  
               "metric":"Total_NoCall_bases",
               "value":112533,
               "type":"simple"
            }
         ],
         "type":"metrics-set"
      },
      {  
         "metric":"GENE2",
         "value":[  
            {  
               "metric":"Exons",
               "value":[  
                  "GENE2_Exon5",
                  {  
                     "chromosome":"chr1",
                     "start":45656,
                     "end":5656667
                  },
                  "GENE2_Exon10",
                  {  
                     "chromosome":"chr1",
                     "start":45656,
                     "end":5656667
                  }
               ],
               "type":"set"
            },
            {  
               "metric":"Precent_no_call",
               "value":0.746464,
               "type":"simple"
            },
            {  
               "metric":"Total_NoCall_bases",
               "value":16842,
               "type":"simple"
            }
         ],
         "type":"metrics-set"
      }
   ]
}
```

### NOTE

Also, this is related to the question here:-
[Converting comma separated file to nested objects json in jq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632107/converting-comma-separated-file-to-nested-objects-json-in-jq)

Thanks for your help in advance.

### Solution I tried from a comma separated input file(See in another question I posted)

```
def parse:
  [
      inputs                     # read lines
    | split(",")                 # split into columns
    | select(length>0)           # eliminate blanks
    | .[:1] + [.[1:-3]] + .[-3:] # normalize columns

  ]
;
def simple(n;v): {metric:n, value:v|tonumber, type:"simple"};
def set(n;v):    {metric:n, value:v,          type:"set"};
def chr(c;s;e):  {chromsome:c, start:s, end:e}; 
def region:
  set(.[0]; [
      set("Exons";  (.[1] | tostring | split(";") |.[0]); 
      chr((.[1] | tostring | split(";") |.[1]),(.[1] | tostring | split(";") |.[2]),(.[1] | tostring | split(";") |.[3]))
     ]

     ),
      simple("Fraction of bases"; .[5]),
      simple("Total_bases"; .[6])
    ]
  )
;
{
   "Regions": parse | map(region)
}
```

I was unable to loop it and read recursively.

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what problem you're facing. SO is not a free coding service.

Comment: Hi Dat,

I am relatively new to using Jq and also I am not a software engineer by profession. My expertise is in genomics and scripting.

I definitely tried getting this to work by creating a JQ function used from an answer earlier question of mine, I was not able to split the sub objects and it was printing whole line. I will edit the question and add what i had tried.

Thanks for your suggestion. I will keep in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the low-level requirements are clear enough, I've assembled the following solution, which behaves exactly in accordance with the example.  However, the higher level requirements are rather sketchy so you may need to make some adjustments.

The low-level requirement (about converting the strings) can be implemented as follows:

```
# Input: a string
def gene2object:
  split(";")
  | [.[0], { chromosome: .[1], 
             start: (.[2]|tonumber),
             end:   (.[3]|tonumber)} ];
```

A solution can now be written quite simply as follows:

```
walk( if type == "object" and .metric == "Exons" 
      then .value |= (map(gene2object)|add) 
      else .
      end )
```

The standard invocation (along the lines of: `jq -f program.jq input.json`) produces the output exactly as described, so I won't repeat it here.

If your jq does not have `walk/1`, then you can snarf its official definition from https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq
That is, search for: `def walk`

Comment: Thanks peak, this solution works well. Can you point me to a manual where I can learn more about complex functions of jq

Comment: 1. The manual is the best place (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/), but see also the FAQ at https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ, the Cookbook https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook, and http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Category:Jq. (2) If your jq does not have `walk` I'd strongly recommending getting a recent version that does (e.g. from `master`).

Comment: Thanks, now I understand more about the SO features. I accepted the answer.